# Add a custom text to items in Woocommerce order received (thank you) page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I have custom bulk discount function where I call two hooks:

- the first one to edit item price in cart: `woocommerce_cart_item_price`,
- the second one to calculate prices before total: `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals`.

Now, I'd like to add discount text **"(10% discount)"** for each item to my order received page.

Is there any hook which could help me achieve something similar I did with prices before order received page?

Answer (score 0):

You can make changes in the `{your theme}\woocommerce\order\order-details-item.php` file. In case if you haven't yet copied to your theme/woocommerce directory, [copy it](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

You can also take use of hooks `woocommerce_order_item_meta_start`, `woocommerce_order_item_meta_end`, which you can find in the mentioned file.

Comment: Customizing template is ideal solution here. However, I would add customization inside `if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ) ) { }` block so my changes only show on `thankyou` page otherwise changes in `order-details-item.php` would show changes in `view-order` and `order-tracking` pages as well.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. I will work this way, I've also managed to implement my bulk discount function with woocommerce_order_item_meta_start. 

I have some problems how to display discount text next to item price.  Is it possible to format price or somehow add html next to item price?

Comment: @JanGale, you are welcome! Sure you can. It'd be better to add it in the mentioned (`order-details-item.php`) template file. Just add the text after the line `<?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?>` wrapped in the HTML you would like. It will be displayed next to item price.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom function hooked in `woocommerce_order_item_name` filter hook to add your custom text "(10% discount)" to each item title:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'custom_orders_items_names', 10, 2 );
function custom_orders_items_names( $item_name, $item ) {
    // Only in thankyou "Order-received" page
    if(is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-received' ))
        $item_name .= ' ' . __('(10% discount)', 'woocommerce');
    return $item_name;
}
```

Code goes in any php file of your active child theme *(or active theme)*.

Tested and works.